# Bottlepy return output if raise HTTPResponse, but give error when raise template

Tags: python, templates, httpresponse, bottle

I have sample code

```
from bottle import HTTPResponse, run, route, template

@route('/')
def hello_world():
    raise HTTPResponse(body='test', status=200)

@route('/test')
def test():
    raise template('<b>Hello {{name}}</b>!', name='World')

run(host='localhost', port=9999)
```

I know, `raise` is not proper way to return data. But I have this code ready, and need to use that.

I want to know, when I `raise HTTPResponse` it works, but when I try `raise template` it gives error.

How can I convince not to use `raise` in application, but not sure what argument I gave to convince?

What is the difference between `raise HTTPResponse` and `return HTTPResponse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`raise` is used exclusively generating exceptions, and as such, expects an object that is inherited from the `BaseException` class.

Since `HTTPResponse' and 'is **not** derived from any sort of exception, it is an illegal operation and generates an error.

Basically, `raise` is for exceptions, don't use it unless you intend to trigger an error to catch or pass up the stack.

Comment: thanks, but `raise` would not give error ir we use `non sub class` of `BaseException` with `raise` ?

Comment: @Lafada To be honest, I am not entirely sure what exactly your comment is asking. However, the entire point of my answer is that `raise` is completely inappropriate to use here, it's madness to try to create work-around in order allow you to `raise` an `HttpResponse` or `template`. If there is some reason you believe that you **must** use `raise`, please edit your question and include that, as it's likely an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Sorry, if this confuse you, I will check what I can do instead of `raise`. I fully agree, I have to use `return` instead of `raise`.

Comment: it's allowed to raise `HTTPResponse` see [here](https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/blob/master/bottle.py#L422) and [here](https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/blob/master/bottle.py#L1952)